# What mistake have I made while creating TRIGGER?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE IMAGE]

After creating the trigger, I got a warning:

> Trigger created with compilation errors

What should I do?

```
SQL> create trigger customer_trig
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON customer1
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  set customer1.t_cost=customer1.pprice*customer1.tq
  6  END;
  7  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> desc customer1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 CID                                                VARCHAR2(10)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 PNAME                                              VARCHAR2(15)
 PPRICE                                             NUMBER(5)
 TQ                                                 NUMBER(5)
 T_COST                                             NUMBER(7)

SQL> insert into customer1 values('ssr345','vikram','book',30,12,0);
insert into customer1 values('ssr345','vikram','book',30,12,0)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'RAYUDU.CUSTOMER_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Comment: Do you really need a trigger? Doesn't Oracle have _computed columns_?

Comment: Please read [Assigning Values to Variables with the Assignment Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#LNPLS-GUID-B91BEA99-974B-4CE7-8B28-A5B78A6918F7)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the trigger properly. You must use `:NEW` for referencing the new value and `ON DELETE` event is not needed here.

I think you need the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CUSTOMER_TRIG BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE 
    --OR DELETE 
    ON CUSTOMER1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.T_COST := :NEW.PPRICE * :NEW.TQ;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jarlh asked Oracle does have computed columns. In Oracle speak that's a virtual column. And is the best solution here. Redefine the column T_COST as a virtual column. If your table already exists then:

```
alter table customer1 drop column t_cost;    
alter table customer1 add ( t_cost number(7) generated always as (pprice * tq ) virtual);
```

Note: The above does not require "generated always" not "virtual" phrases but does enhance readability (at least IMO);